# React hook form doesn't watch a field in an array field

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a field array in my react hook form which has a checkbox field. I would like to watch that field but I am only able to watch the whole array field like this:

```
const Period = ({ item, index, datepicker }) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext<InntektFormValues>();
    const value = useWatch({
        control,
        name: "incomes",
    });


    return value[index].selected datepicker : <div className="min-w-[160px]"></div>;
};
```

This is where I'm mapping over the field array:

```
export const IncomeTable = () => {
    const { control } = useFormContext<IncomeFormValues>();
    const incomeField = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: "incomes",
    });

   
    return ({incomes.fields.map((item, index) => (
                    <TableRowWrapper
                        key={item.id}
                        cells={[
                            <Period
                                item={item}
                                index={index}
                                datepicker={
                                    <FormControlledDatePicker
                                        key={`incomes[${index}].from`}
                                        name={`incomes[${index}].from`}
                                        label="From"
                                        placeholder="DD.MM.ÅÅÅÅ"
                                        defaultValue={item?.from ?? null}
                                        hideLabel
                                    />
                                }
                            />,
```

I tried to watch only the selected field and not the whole array like this:

```
const Periode = ({ item, index, datepicker }) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext<InntektFormValues>();
    const value = useWatch({
        control,
        name: `incomes[${index}].selected`,
    });
```

But that throws a Typescript error:

> No overload matches this call.

Why can't I watch just a field from a field array?

Comment: please check `Controlled Field Array` example provided on https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/ if possible put code in codesandbox, i will check

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access .selected property which is not registered in react-hook-form. RHF `useWatch` watches for "value" property of registered fields, not for "selected" property.

This should work:

```js
const Periode = ({ item, index, datepicker }) => {
    const { control } = useFormContext<InntektFormValues>();
    const value = useWatch({
        control,
        name: `incomes[${index}]`,
    });
```

I've built it in a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-forked-onmmtg?file=/src/index.tsx), you can check it out here (just open the console and try to append more fields, then toggle each checkboxes, you'll see it'll only log the first checkbox value).

If that also won't work, change the naming to incomes.[index] instead of incomes[index].